# Use location field as address in natbib

Tags: natbib

In most citations in my area (CS), the location field (location of conference) in the bibtex entry is more relevant than the address (address of publisher, almost always New York, NY).

```
@inproceedings{somepaper-1995,
 author = {Doe, John and Doe, Jane},
 title = {An Interesting Submission},
 booktitle = {Proceedings of the 1995 ACM Symposium on Principles of Distributed Computing},
 series = {PODC '95},
 year = {1995},
 location = {Ottowa, Ontario, Canada},
 publisher = {ACM},
 address = {New York, NY, USA},
}
```

Most bst styles default to using the address in the citation, that is, they cite the above entry as:

> John Doe and Jane Doe. 1995. An Interesting Submission.
>   In Proceedings of the 1995 ACM Symposium on Principles of Distributed Computing (PODC ’95). ACM, New York, NY, USA.

However, most papers in my area use the location information in the citation, rather than the address, that is, they would cite the above paper as:

> John Doe and Jane Doe. 1995. An Interesting Submission.
>   In Proceedings of the 1995 ACM Symposium on Principles of Distributed Computing (PODC ’95). ACM, Ottowa, Ontario, Canada.

In the past I've used biblatex to solve this problem by automatically substituting the location (when existent) where the address is normally placed - it does this by default.  Unfortunately, the journal publisher I'm submitting to requires the use of the natbib package.  So:

In natbib, is there a way to automatically use the location field contents to replace the address field contents in the bibliography?

Comment: Hi. I don't know of an easy way to do this, as it would require redefining the natbib style. Is it possible to use the `note` field?

Comment: I'd rather not, as it would require modifying every entry in the .bib database - which is what I'm trying to avoid in the first place.  At this point I've exported the relevant entries into a new .bib file using bibexport and just modified the fields here.